# Probability Type I error

Tags: statistics

I have these values:

A sample of size $100$ is taken from the population.
Standard Deviation is $5$.

Average is $125$.

$H_0$: $\mu =125$ Against $H_a$: $\mu <125$

Accept $H_0$ if the sample mean is $\bar{\mathbb{x}} ≥ 124$
Reject $H_0$ if the sample mean  $\bar{\mathbb{x}} < 124 $

Find the probability of making a Type I error.

I did:

Variance$\; =25$, because S.D. is $5$ then,

$$Z= \frac{\bar{\mathbb{x}} -\mu}{\text{S.D.}/\sqrt{100}}$$

which is : $ Z=\frac{124-125}{5/10}=-2 $

$1- \Phi (-2)=1-0.97725=0.023$

The probability of making a type I error is $2.3%$.

Am I correct? Can anyone let me know if this is correct?

thanks

Comment: You have the right result but it's $\Phi(-2)$, not $1-\Phi(-2)$.

Comment: I disagree with Matt. This kind of question seems perfectly fine here, in my opinion. The other site seems to be more focused on data analysis and stuff like that. Feel free to continue posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You work seems fine, except for the final step as Augustin pointed out.

In terms of probability, recall that we are seeking the probability that $\bar x < 124$ given that the $\mu = 125$. This means
$$P(\bar x <124|\mu = 125)$$
By standardizing, we get

\begin{align*}
P(\bar x <124|\mu = 125) &= P\left(Z < \frac{124-125}{5/\sqrt{100}}\bigg|\mu
= 125\right) \\
&= P(Z<-2|\mu = 125) \\
&= \Phi(-2) \\
&= 0.02275013
\end{align*}
In simpler terms (if you don't know probability), we are looking for the "area to the left" of $-2$ under the normal curve.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have one question I am not sure if you can help but when I am using the table book I have the table for the Normal distribution functions and I have  the inverse of the z-transformation, I don't know which one to use.I am reading my notes and I saw P(z < tabulated value) which is $ 1- \phi(z) $  and because I obtained the value -2 I used $ 1-\phi(-2)  $ using values of the normal distribution but I did it wrong.

Comment: @user290335 1. The area under the curve to the left of $z$ is usually denoted with capital `\Phi(z)` $\Phi(z)$. 2. I think I understand what you are asking. Look at the normal curve and notice that there is symmetry when looking at the area under the curve. Specifically, $\Phi(-2)$ has the same area as $1-\Phi(2)$. In other words, the area to the left of $-2$ is the same as the area to the right of $2$. The area to the right of $2$ is $1-\Phi(2)$.

Comment: so $ \phi (-2) $ is the same as $ 1- \phi(2)  $

Comment: @user290335 If you examine the the curve and the area under it, you will see that it is true.

Comment: I understood, thank you for your help

Comment: @user290335 No problem. Good luck!